# How to find a group midpoint of a pandas or python array?

Tags: python, pandas

There is an array, that look like that (it's actually a column in a pandas dataframe, but any suggestions how to make in a plain python would also work)

```py
[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1, 0]
```

For each subsequence of `1`s I need to find a midpoint position: an index of a point in the middle of this subsequence, or the closest to it. So for the example above, these would be 6 for the first subsequence, 18 for the second etc.

It can be easily done with just a naive looping, but I wonder if there is more efficient way (maybe built-in pandas function?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `groupby`:

1. Use the series (i.e. column) index to `groupby` sequences of 0s and 1s with `srs.ne(srs.shift()).cumsum()`
2. Get the average of the first and last indices for each sequence
3. Keep only the `unique` values where the original column value is 1

```
srs = pd.Series([0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0])
g = srs.index.to_series().groupby(srs.ne(srs.shift()).cumsum())

>>> g.transform("first").add(g.transform("last")).floordiv(2).where(srs.eq(1)).dropna().unique()
array([ 6., 18., 25.])
```

Answer (score 2):

For a pure Python solution, you can use itertools.groupby which groups keys based on sequential uniqueness by default.

```py
import itertools

data = [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1, 0]

start = 0
midpoints = []
for key, group in itertools.groupby(data):
    group = list(group)
    if key == 1:
        midpoints.append(start + (len(group) // 2))
    start += len(group)

print(midpoints)
[6, 18, 25]
```

---

For a pandas solution, we filter our data first, then use some groupby tricks to perform a groupby operation akin to `itertools.groupby`, and finally get the size and start position of each group. From there, we simply add the start position of the group to half of the size, and we get the approximate midpoint.

```py
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1, 0])

midpoints = (
    s.loc[lambda s: s.eq(1)]
    .groupby(s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum())
    .agg(['idxmin', 'size'])
    .eval('size // 2 + idxmin')
    # .eval("size.floordiv(2) + idxmin") # alternatively try
)

print(midpoints)
2     6
4    18
6    25
dtype: int64
```

Comment: the pandas code returns 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'VariableNode' and 'int'

Comment: What version of `pandas` are you working with? This runs for me on `pd.__version__ == 1.4.1`